# Oracle dynamic database link from variables

Tags: database, oracle, dynamic, hyperlink

i have 3 oracle databases: db1, db2, db3.
I have created database links from db1 to db2 and db3, called db002link and db003link.
Now i have a procedure which takes as input a date and takes different actions on tables according to that input. One of them though requires to connect to one of the db2 or db3 databases. Before the execution of the procedure, i don't not know to which one, as it depends on the data gathered by the procedure itself in previous steps.
So i need to concatenate some variables to create the db link and then connect through it.

i have the variable v_dbnumber which is varchar(3) and looks like '003' for instance and is the result of a select from a table. I have tried the following:

```
v_dbconn := 'db'||v_dbnumber||'link'
```

But then the next step, `select * from s1.t1@v_dbconn` gets a compilation error for the procedure: ORA-04052, ORA-00604, ORA-02019 referring to the non existing connection. But the object is shown as:
@v_dbconn instead of @db003link.

Can somebody please help me with this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the statement to be dynamic, you'd need to use dynamic SQL.

If you just want to open a cursor using a dynamically generated SQL statement, you can do something like

```
DECLARE
  l_sql_stmt varchar2(1000);
  l_dblink   varchar2(100) := 'db002link';
  l_rc       sys_refcursor;
BEGIN
  l_sql := 'select * from s1.t1@' || l_dblink;
  open l_rc for l_sql;
END;
```

Normally, though, you're doing something with the data that you're selecting.  That would generally involve using either `dbms_sql` or `EXECUTE IMMEDIATE` to execute the statement and fetch data into some local variable or collection.  Assuming that the table definitions are the same in each of the databases, you could do something like

```
EXECUTE IMMEDIATE l_sql
   BULK COLLECT INTO <<some appropriate collection>>
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution is very similar to Justin's, though I am using a procedure with dynamic sql.

```
APPS@tst> CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE test_dblink(
  2      db_link VARCHAR2 )
  3  AS
  4    v_sql VARCHAR2(500);
  5    v_test dual.dummy%TYPE;
  6  BEGIN
  7    v_sql := 'select dummy from dual@'|| db_link;
  8    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_sql INTO v_test;
  9    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_test);
 10  END;
 11  /

Procedure created.

APPS@tst> commit;

Commit complete.

APPS@tst> 
APPS@tst> 
APPS@tst> 
APPS@tst> begin
  2  test_dblink('db003link');
  3  end;
  4  /
X

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.
```

This does not have error handling and it assumes one record will be returned (typically not a good assumption).

Comment: Thanks, i have taken the same approach, implemented into a procedure.